# Find hex number inside Hex Range in C+/C++

Tags: c++, hex

I have min and max in Hex range as shown, and I like to search/check if this hex number 0D08 is belong to hex range below. 
Thanks in advance.

Andrew
Should I do it in array? {"0000","0001",......"03FF"}, but would be too much.

```
0000H - 03FFH
```

Comment: Convert the hex to `int` and compare the `int` values.

Comment: Why not convert min, and max, and number to decimals and simply do `if ( number >= min && number <= max )` ?

Comment: How are the hex values known to you? As string, as numbers? They are simply numbers - so the regular rules of mathematics apply. After all hex is just a grouping of binary digits, and that's actually how computers represent numbers internally. Did you think about this before posting your question?

Comment: 0x03FF is 1023 in Decimal, an array with a 1024 entries would be very inefficient just to compare the range. Convert it as an `int` then simply compare...

Comment: Floris: no, but I would not expect simple comparison working and turn out everyone has same answer. I thought you had asked question about hex number?  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do normal comparison :-

```
x=0xd08;

min = 0x0;   // decimal 0
max = 0x3ff; // decimal 1023

if ( x>=min  && x <= max){
//Do Stuff

}
```

Comment: This is a nice succinct way to show how to do it. Gets my vote.

Comment: You can do that, I thought it would be too simple:--). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to first convert the `hex` to `int` and then compare it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use comparison operators. You'll find it useful to know hex numbers may directly be represented in C++ using the notation `0xHHHH`, where `H` ranges, naturally, from `0` to `F`.

```
bool check_range(int x)
{
    return x > 0x0000 && x < 0x03FF;
}

if(check_range(0x0D08))
    //do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Brunocodutra.  Which one should I accept? both answers are looking good.

Comment: @AndrewS [The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)